# php deleting cookie (cant do it via set_cookie)

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm trying to delete my cookie when user click on logout link. But i cant do it via set_cookie and set -time. There appears header modify error - its already sent. Is there any other way to delete cookie?

Comment: Just don't output anything before

Answer (score 1):

You must delete the cookie before printing any text/html.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete any cookies before cookies are sent to the browser along in headers.  You are getting this error because you are likely trying to unset a cookie after some sort of output has been sent to the browser.  This is not allowed and will not work.